# Did Obama enable the US gov't to spend close to 20,000 dollars per month on every illegal immigrant's child?

Tags: united-states, immigration, barack-obama

This "meme"

http://static.politifact.com.s3.amazonaws.com/politifact/photos/Obama_paying_illegal_kids_FB_post_1.jpg

managed to get circulated to my facebook. I looked it up and according to politfact the numbers are "accurate".

I just wish to know if this is true and how is this even possible.

Comment: "I looked it up and according to pf the numbers are "accurate". I just wish to know if this is true and how is this even possible." So you read the PolitiFact article, but you missed the fact that those numbers were completely misleading and the fact that PolitiFact itself rated the entire meme "Mostly false"?

Comment: @userLTK the original content was tempered with so I'm not sure the accusation is still valid.

Answer (score 6):

Building on Brythan's [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/31303/12743).

The main claims of this meme are false and purposefully misleading.

In other words, this meme is **fake news**.

The meme shows three captions:

> American families work hard to earn **$4,250** a month
>
> Obama is spending **$18,972** a month on each illegal immigrant child
>
> LIKE
>
> if you're sick of Obama **rewarding** illegal immigrants!

1. "The $18,972-a-month figure comes from what it cost the federal government to address a surge of tens of thousands of children from Central America for four months in 2014." This "covered housing, medical care, and educational and recreational activities, including staff pay and benefits, food, clothing, utilities and linens, for four months, from May to September 2014." [source](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2015/apr/17/america/meme-compares-spending-undocumented-immigrants-typ/)
2. Not all undocumented children immigrant are in detention facilities. So by using the Universal quantifier "on each" in front of illegal immigrant's child, the main point implied in the claim is false.
3. This was the cost of temporary detention and services "during a surge of tens of thousands of children from Central America for four months in 2014." It's pretty clear from the [article](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2015/apr/17/america/meme-compares-spending-undocumented-immigrants-typ/) that this is not (and this was not) an ongoing expense (despite the meme implying otherwise).
4. The meme itself also says "If you're sick of Obama rewarding illegal immigrants" with "rewarding" in bold font. Claiming that money spent on detention centers, including the cost of staff, for children of undocumented immigrants is a reward for undocumented immigrants is also completely false. Detention does not equate reward.
5. The meme also makes use of imagery showing a picture contrasting a family with a little bit of cash in front of them and a picture of a smiling Obama with lots of cash in front of him. Combined with the captions, this is implying that this was a cash gift to the immigrants. But if one doesn't even read the captions and just looks at the imagery, the implied narrative is that the smiling Obama was the recipient of all that cash, to the detriment of the family on the left with the crying little girl, the concerned mother, and the frowning dad.

Answer (score 2):

The source of that copy of that image is [Politifact](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2015/apr/17/america/meme-compares-spending-undocumented-immigrants-typ/).  They examine the merits of the claim.  They determined:

1. The $18,972 is how much the federal government paid per bed to house children at two sites from May to September of 2014.
2. This was temporary housing.  There was a sudden influx of immigrant children that overwhelmed the existing system.  It's not clear that this is ongoing rather than just something they did in those four months.
3. This is only a small portion of the overall undocumented child immigrant population.  This temporary arrangement says nothing about how much it costs in general.

They did not determine what exactly was being purchased.  From context we can infer that these were detention facilities.  So part of the costs are providing security.  And of course it costs more to provide security in a place that is only temporary.